# NDK r9c - does not support std::future

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have the below source code using std::future.

```
#include<future>
std::future<int> A;
```

However, when I try to compile it with NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.8 in Application.mk file, it throws the error "std::future A" has incomplete type etc."

I tried looking up for future.h within the android-ndk-r9c folder, however, I couldn't find it. Does anyone know if NDK supports std::future at all? If so, which version has this support?

Comment: You should look for file named `future`, not `future.h`, STL style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in one of my above comments, I'm able to compile it by specifying armeabi-v7a as target instead of armeabi.

```
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.8
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_ABI :=armeabi-v7a
```

Answer (score 6):

It seems std::future isn't available with any stl library and compilers as of ndk-r9c.

Starting with ndk r9d, you can use llvm's libc++ library. The support is described as "experimental" but it seems to work quite well.

Instead of your currently chosen STL library (gnustl I guess ?), use `c++_shared` or `c++_static` in your *Application.mk*, like so:

`APP_ABI := all
APP_STL := c++_shared
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := clang`

If you encounter some runtime issues with static version, you can add `LIBCXX_FORCE_REBUILD := true` inside Application.mk as well to force rebuilding it properly.

Comment: I tried above solution, however, when I specify APP_STL := c++_shared or c++_static and TOOLCHAIN_VERSION:= 4.8, it throws some error "fatal error: ext/atomicity.h: No such file or directory". Also, when I give TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := clang, it throws error "invalid argument -std=gnustl++11 not allowed with C/ObjC". Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: When using clang, `-std=c++11` is default and works, but gnustl++11 isn't supported. To have ext/atomicity.h with the NDK you need to use gnustl_shared or gnustl_static.. but in this case you will not have std::future. You shouldn't mix these libraries, you need to choose one regarding the features you need the most.

Comment: I see. Is it not possible to use both at all?

Comment: It's almost impossible, and in any case that would make this possible: this would require heavy modifications of your code and could still be buggy.

Comment: I have been experimenting with different options and when I specify NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.8, APP_STL := gnustl_static and APP_ABI:=armeabi-v7a, I get no compilation errors and my code works. I was having all these problems with APP_ABI:=armeabi. Not able to understand the complete reasoning though.

Answer (score 3):

@pree: I am currently experimenting with the same settings in Application.mk:

```
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a

APP_STL := gnustl_static

APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti --std=c++11

NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.8
```

However, while my code is working fine on a Nexus 10, the app freezes on my LG phone.

EDIT: I have narrowed down the problem. The code I am running is the following:

```
auto task1 = std::packaged_task<void()>([]() {
    LOG_INFO("Task1 starting");
    sleep(5);
    LOG_INFO("Task1 finishing");
});
auto fut1 = task1.get_future();

auto task2 = std::packaged_task<void()>([]() {
    LOG_INFO("Task2 starting");
    sleep(10);
    LOG_INFO("Task2 finishing");
});
auto fut2 = task2.get_future();

std::thread([&](){task1();}).detach();
std::thread([&](){task2();}).detach();

LOG_INFO("waiting for task1");
fut1.wait();
LOG_INFO("waiting for task1 done");

LOG_INFO("waiting for task2");
fut2.wait();
LOG_INFO("waiting for task2 done");
```

On the Nexus 10 this code produces the following output:

```
 18:14:15.365: waiting for task1
 18:14:15.365: Task1 starting
 18:14:15.365: Task2 starting
 18:14:20.370: Task1 finishing
 18:14:20.370: waiting for task1 done
 18:14:20.370: waiting for task2
 18:14:25.365: Task2 finishing
 18:14:25.365: waiting for task2 done
```

While on another device (LG phone), I get the following output:

```
 18:23:21.999: Task1 starting
 18:23:21.999: waiting for task1
 18:23:26.999: Task1 finishing
 18:23:26.999: waiting for task1 done
 18:23:26.999: waiting for task2
 18:23:26.999: Task2 starting
 18:23:37.178: Task2 finishing
 18:23:37.178: waiting for task2 done
```

This means on the LG device, the second task waits for the first one to be completed until it starts.
However, the problem seems to originate from std::packed_task, rather then from std::future, because the following code behaves as expected on both devices:

```
std::promise<void> promise1;
auto task1 = std::function<void()>([&]() {
    LOG_INFO("Task1 starting");
    sleep(5);
    promise1.set_value();
    LOG_INFO("Task1 finishing");
});
auto fut1 = promise1.get_future();

std::promise<void> promise2;
auto task2 = std::function<void()>([&]() {
    LOG_INFO("Task2 starting");
    sleep(10);
    promise2.set_value();
    LOG_INFO("Task2 finishing");
});
auto fut2 = promise2.get_future();

std::thread([&](){task1();}).detach();
std::thread([&](){task2();}).detach();

LOG_INFO("waiting for task1");
fut1.wait();
LOG_INFO("waiting for task1 done");

LOG_INFO("waiting for task2");
fut2.wait();
LOG_INFO("waiting for task2 done");
```

Am I maybe doing something wrong here?

Comment: and what if you use APP_ABI := armeabi? does it work on both the devices then?

Comment: No. In this case it doesn't even compile.

Comment: Oh. that's because you are using std::future etc?

Comment: Yes. I'm getting errors like "aggregate 'std::future<int> test' has incomplete type and cannot be defined".

Comment: Do you think you can check hardware info on your LG phone? One way to check this is to download android system info app from the market. Click System tab and then Buildinfos. It will show you two things. CPU ABI and CPU ABI2. Can you check both?

Comment: CPU ABI: armeabi-v7a
CPU ABI2: armeabi

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. Using std::async with std::launch::async on an Android device with API <16 does not work, the thread does not start. While it will work on a more modern device. Even, the same device with a different system image works. I'm using a Galaxy Nexus with different system images: API 15 and API 16. 15 fails, 16 works. Removing the launch policy works too, but I want to specify async on my code.