# std::async problems depending on Android version

Tags: android, c++, c++11, asynchronous, android-ndk

I'm currently developing a native application that may run on Android devices from API 14. I'm using std::async in my code and so far it did not give any problems with API 16 to API 19 devices, but API 14 and 15 are behaving in a different way:

- When I'm using std::launch::async, the function is not executing. The wait() call to the returned std::future is blocking permanently.
- When I don't set the policy, it works. (I presume, it uses deferred).

Example:

```
std::async(std::launch::async, &foo) <-- never running foo
std::async(&foo) <-- runs foo
```

If I flash an API 16 image on the same device, async works as expected.

I'm using CLang3.4 and the latest toolchain.

I'm also using gnustl_static.

I've read similar issues, like: [NDK r9c - does not support std::future](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23839964/ndk-r9c-does-not-support-stdfuture/24067386#24067386) where the user reports that the LG phone will not start the second task until the first ended.

Two questions:

- Why the different behavior depending on the Android version?
- If I am linking the same gnustd_static library, why the std::async behaves different?